# Django: When saving issue

Tags: python, django

I's using django 1.6 and have a model for a blog but when saving the content I get category id can not be blank but I don't understand this error. I have tried looking at the code trying different things but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.title

    @permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('view_category', None, {'slug': self.slug})

class Blog(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
    extended = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Blog post'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Blog posts'
        ordering = ('-updated',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.title

    @permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self, ):
        return('view_questions', None, {'slug': self.slug,})


    def save(self):
        super(Blog, self).save()
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = '%d/%s' % (
                self.pk, slugify(self.title)
            )
        super(Blog, self).save()
```

Comment: you shouldnt call super twice.

Comment: I don't think you understand what a slug field is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when saving the content I get category id can not be blank but I don't
>   understand this error.

```
category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

That line means that a blog post must belong to a category. In your blog table, the category foreign key is called category_id.

You can either make sure to add a category; blog.category = Category.objects.get(...) for example OR you can make the category optional:

```
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, blank=True, null=True)
```